# git format-patch < everything since last svn rebase >

Tags: git, git-svn, patch

I'm trying to mash all my changes since I last pushed to the svn server into one big patch that I can email to my coworker for review. Can I do this with `git format-patch` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `git format-patch origin/master` to get all the patches since your current branch forked from the server. (The HEAD is assumed as the final argument in the command, so you are getting `origin/master..HEAD`.)

However, as VonC hints at, that could potentially create a lot of files: one .patch file for every commit you made! If you want just a single big patch file, the `git-diff` syntax he mentions should to the trick. (`git diff origin/master.. > bigpatch.patch` would give you all the changes since the common ancestor of your HEAD and the server.)

Answer (score 1):

For dealing with *one* file, **[`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)** is more appropriate (for patches of text files)

```
git diff R1..R2 > patchR1R2.diff
```