# Is it possible to move a bunch of files from one git repository to another while preserving (most) history?

Tags: git

I added some files to the wrong repository and didn't realize until later, once they already had quite a bit of history (just linear revisions, no branching or anything).

Is it possible to get these files and move them to another git repository together with their history? I don't care if their remnants stay in their current one or not, as long as the new one has it all.

Comment: I'm no GIT expert but could you: 1. clone the target repo. 2. push the wrong source into the cloned target. 3. rebase the changesets you want to keep. 4. push only those changesets back to the original repo? As I said, I'm not an GIT expert so I don't even know if this is possible.

Comment: Also checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365541/how-to-move-files-from-one-git-repo-to-another-not-a-clone-preserving-history) (near duplicate) question. With thousands of views, it might be the more authoritative answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `git log -p <filename> > <patchfile>` (see [doc](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)) you can export the whole history of the file which can then be applied to the other repo via `git apply --reverse --index <patchfile>`. However this does not recreate the commits, and I [haven't figured out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194240/how-can-a-patchfile-created-with-git-log-p-filename-be-applied-to-create-all) the switch for `git-apply` to do this.

If you want to get rid of the file in the original repo, see ["How do I remove sensitive files from git’s history?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/how-do-i-remove-sensitive-files-from-gits-history).

Comment: I ended up rubyscripting output of git log -p, and turning it into a series of patch/git add/git commit - worked well enough for this simple case, even if it feels really wrong.

Comment: @taw would you mind posting that script as an answer to [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194240/how-can-a-patchfile-created-with-git-log-p-filename-be-applied-to-create-all) then? A workaround is better than nothing, and future visitors might appreciate this help

Comment: With git version 1.7.10.3 `git apply --reverse --indexed <patchfile>` will return with `error: unknown option `indexed'`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following.

1. Use `git fetch` to pull the tip of the branch with the desired files from the wrong repository into the right repository.
2. Use `git filter-branch` with either a `--tree-filter` or `--index-filter` to remove everything other than the desired files from the fetched branch.
3. Use `git rebase` or reapply the tidied up commits onto an appropriate main branch in the right repository.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a [`git format-patch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html) on the branch you a reworking on, to generate patches for the last commits improperly made on that repo.
See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917727/git-format-patch-everything-since-last-svn-rebase).

You would then apply those path on the correct repo.
And you would `reset --hard` your current branch in order to get rid of the extra commit.