# How can a patchfile created with `git-log -p <filename>` be applied to create all the commits included?

Tags: git, history, commit, patch, git-log

Background: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192828/is-it-possible-to-move-a-bunch-of-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-while/3192912#3192912). `git apply <patchfile>` just recreates the file but without committing the history, which in this case would be desireable. Is there any switch for `git-apply` to do so? Or is there a way to convert the patchfile into a `git-am` compatible file? (Currently, git-am complains "Patch format detection failed")

Comment: If you've got a range of commits that you want to apply you're usually much better off creating a bundle, or simply fetching and rebasing than trying to re-create commits from a `log -p` output.

Comment: @Charles is that also possible for a single file's history? That's what the mentioned question is about, so I simply tried `git log -p <filename> > <patchfile>` to get the patch...

Comment: `git apply` is more of an opposite to `git diff` than `log -p` so without manually splitting the output I don't think it's possible (or not easy, anyway). If you can get a bundle between the two repositories then I think it would be much easier to manipulate the original branch to apply to a single file (e.g. using `filter-branch`) and then rebase it than to fiddle with text based patches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked, so here it is.

I used this script, but it's all rather fragile. Treat it an as inspiration, not as a reasonable solution.

It extracts (date / author / commit message / patch) from output of `git log -p`, and then runs `patch`+`git add`+`git apply` for all, in reverse order.

There's probably some way of automatically figuring out correct `patch_level`, but I didn't bother. And pass author to `git apply` if it's not all you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class String
  def shell_escape
    if empty?
      "''"
    elsif %r{\A[0-9A-Za-z+,./:=@_-]+\z} =~ self
      self
    else
      result = ''
      scan(/('+)|[^']+/) {
        if $1
          result << %q{\'} * $1.length
        else
          result << "'#{$&}'"
        end
      }
      result
    end
  end
end

dir1, dir2, *files = ARGV

patchlog = Dir.chdir(dir1){`git log -p #{files.map(&:shell_escape).join(" ")}`}

patches = []
patchlog.each_line{|line|
  if line =~ /\Acommit/
    patches << {}
  elsif line =~ /\A(Author|Date):\s*(.*)/
    patches[-1][$1] = $2
  elsif patches[-1][:diff].nil? and line !~ /\Adiff/
    (patches[-1][:msg] ||= "") << line
  else
    (patches[-1][:diff] ||= "") << line
  end
}

patch_level = 2
skip = 0
dry_run = false

patches.reverse[skip..-1].each{|patch|
  author = patch["Author"].strip
  date = patch["Date"].strip
  msg = patch[:msg].strip
  diff = patch[:diff]

  if dry_run
    puts ["git", "commit", "-m", msg, "--date", date].join(" ")
    next
  end

  Dir.chdir(dir2){
    IO.popen("patch -p#{patch_level}", "w"){|fh|
      fh.puts diff
    }
    system "git", "add", *files
    system "git", "commit", "-m", msg, "--date", date
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

look into [`git quiltimport`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-quiltimport.html). You provide a directory where the command finds a file called "series". In this file you simply mention the names of the patchfiles, in order which it will apply them". The text prior to the actuall diff in the file is used as commit comment, the filename (minus the .patch) is used as headline, and it tries to find the author in each patch, if none are found you get asked for it.