# How to move a file from one git repository to another while preserving history

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I am trying to move a single file (call it foo.txt) from one repository to another (unrelated) repository, preserving its history. [ebneter's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365541/how-to-move-files-from-one-git-repo-to-another-not-a-clone-preserving-history) shows how to do this for a subdirectory. [taw's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192828/is-it-possible-to-move-a-bunch-of-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-while) has some hints and suggestions, but not a step-by-step procedure to follow. [jkeating's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998987/splitting-a-set-of-files-within-a-git-repo-into-their-own-repository-preserving) looked promising, but didn't work for me. Google searches came up empty for this particular use case. What I am looking for is a clear sequence of commands to accomplish this.

The sequence of commands I started to follow was this:

```
$ git clone source-repo/ source-repo-copy
$ cd source-repo-copy
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'test ! "$@" = "foo.txt" && \
  git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch $@ || true' --prune-empty
```

The logic of my filter command is to `git rm` all files that are not foo.txt. I added the `|| true` to the command to force it to have a zero return value to satisfy filter-branch.

My intention was to set source-repo-copy as a remote for my target repository (target-repo), and assuming `git filter-branch` filtered out everything but foo.txt, fetch and merge source-repo-copy into target-repo. Unfortunately, the `git filter-branch` command seemed to have no effect. It ran with no errors and appeared to grind through the 600+ commits in source-repo, but when it finished, the `git log` and files in source-repo-copy looked the same. Shouldn't all files but foo.txt be missing and all commits that didn't touch it be gone from the log?

At this point I don't know how to proceed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move files from one git repo to another (not a clone), preserving history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365541/how-to-move-files-from-one-git-repo-to-another-not-a-clone-preserving-history)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This worked for me, but with a whole directory.

As shown [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130818084317/http://www.mactricks.de/de/Programmieren/VCS/git/repo_split)

```
~$ cd neu
~/neu$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter FooBar HEAD
~/neu$ git reset --hard
~/neu$ git remote rm origin
~/neu$ rm -r .git/refs/original/
~/neu$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all
~/neu$ git gc --aggressive
~/neu$ git prune
~/neu$ git remote add origin git://github.com/FooBar/neu.git
```

**EDIT: For a single file:**

Filter the directory first:

```
 git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter myDirectory -- --all
```

Filter the single file:

```
 git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch $(git ls-files | grep -v 'keepthisfile.txt')"
```

Do some cleanup:

```
 git reset --hard
 git gc --aggressive
 git prune
```

This should do it.

Comment: Yes, the `--subdirectory-filter` examples all seem straightforward, but I'm looking to move a single file, not a subdirectory. Any ideas with that?

Comment: please try it on a testrepo first, the new solution works for me

Comment: I filtered the directory as you suggested, using '.' instead of 'myDirectory'. I was left with zero files in the directory (just .git). `git log` showed only merge commits (12 of them). I then filtered the single file. I got errors because `git rm` was being called with an empty parameter list. I added `|| true` to the end of the command to  prevent git rm's complaints from aborting the filter. After that, still zero files, and only 4 merge commits in `git log`. I finished up with `git reset/gc/prune` but saw no change. I guess it didn't work. :( I'm glad I tried this on a test repo. :)

Comment: Please upload a testrepo with your structure on github or something. (Or tell me the hierachy). If the git consists of testDir/myFile{1..3}.txt it works fine. The filter for the single file can't work if ur directory is empty,  try to irgnore the directory filter and step on the filter the single. There's a chance your shell doesn't recognize the command well.

git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch $(git ls-files | grep -v "keepFile.txt")'

Comment: Just after I posted the question I went on vacation, and haven't been able to test this answer thoroughly. Still, I appreciate blang's work. You get the check mark. :)

Comment: TortoiseGit makes this trivial, at least in Windows (right-click-drag the files from one explorer window to another, and select `Git Copy and add files to this WC`). Any idea how this is implemented under the hood, and whether it can be done similarly at the command line? I'd be really surprised if it removes and then restores the `origin`, or makes a temporary clone, though I guess it's possible...

Comment: It wasn't clear to me at first the steps to take for a single file rather than directory. This is my understanding, for anyone similarly confused: The two `filter-branch` commands in the EDIT should replace the one `filter-branch` command in the original code. Then, the "Do some cleanup" commands are actually included in the rest of the original code section and should be run as such. Finally, you need to `git push origin new-branch`.

Comment: This can also be used for more than one file by modifying the `grep` statement with an or: `grep -v  'file1\|file2\|file3'`