# Git: how to move a subtree from one repo to another?

Tags: git, version-control

How do I move files **and history** from one git repo to another?

I have a private git repo with some files that I would now like to put in a public, unrelated git repo, retaining their history.

Comment: What do you want the new repo to look like? You won't be able to merge the two histories completely without rewriting all commits of the new repo (starting from the time of the oldest commit in the old repo)...

Comment: I just want the files added to the pubic repo.

Comment: How about `cp -R src .; git add -A; git commit`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move a file from one git repository to another while preserving history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524578/how-to-move-a-file-from-one-git-repository-to-another-while-preserving-history)

Comment: @jtbandes, sure, but that misses the part I bolded in the question... how to carry the file history along.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move files from one git repo to another (not a clone), preserving history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365541/how-to-move-files-from-one-git-repo-to-another-not-a-clone-preserving-history)

Comment: My remark above was incorrect. As long as you're able to get the commits into the repo, you actually can just merge them in with your master branch; you'll have two starting points but one `master`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sync another repo with files and history from your local repository you may add the other repo as a new remote and push all changes.

```
git remote add anotherrepo <url to another repo>
git push anotherrepo master
```

This will push local master to the other repo, you may need to change this if you have other names for your branches.

Comment: You don't even need to add the remote.  Just use the url directly.